# In .NET C# .aspx pages is it possible to include a file based on a parameter?

Tags: asp.net

I tried

```
<!--#include virtual="<%= incFile %>" -->
```

with no luck.

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For client side code (html, javascript etc) check [How To Dynamically Include Files in ASP.NET](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/306575).

If you are talking about server side executable code, I suggest you to take advantage of [Object Oriented Programming](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/219869/Object-Oriented-Programming-in-Csharp-NET) and/or [User Controls (.ascx)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/y6wb1a0e.aspx)